# How to sequentially process methods of same class instance in nodejs using Aync

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, async.js

I have Class with some set of functions with it.

Need to process the function in sequence. I Tried using [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) but when function is executing class object as i passed as this is undefined .

ASYNC Series code:

```
const obj = new Class();

const steps = [
obj.test,
async.apply(obj.fun1, ""),
obj.fun2,
async.apply(obj.fun3, ""),
async.apply(obj.fun4, ""),
async.apply(obj.fun6, "",""),\
];

async.series(steps,
(err, result) => {
  if (!result) {
     return;
  }
});
```

When this is executing , am getting error from *fun1* that

> "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

its because class which is initiated before async.series is not getting passed properly to function internally when its being executed.

Can some one help me in resolving this issue like how to pass series of class function in async.series

Comment: Read the `Binding a context to an iteratee` section on the page you referred to.

Comment: Are these methods asynchronous?  If not, you can just call them sequentially - you don't need an async library for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes they are async based methods.

Comment: @A.K - So how do you know when they're done then?  Do they return a promise?  Do they use a callback?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes I return Promise<boolean> type ! For example : fun1 =  async () =>{ return true;} !! This should be okay for async.series to work right ?

Comment: Asynchronous or otherwise, you're passing unbound member functions, this will cause a crash that has nothing to do with asynchrony if any of those member functions reference use `this`. This is the case for any JavaScript code

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes based on document i have added bind it to so that instance is binded to the async.js 

But I'm having trouble , even before series is completed next set f codes started to execute i couldn't do Await anywhere... 

I Tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61705880/11109465) already but i just wanna explore same king in async.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the methods that are asynchronous return promises (instead of using callbacks), then you can just use `await` to sequence them.

```
async function someFunction() 

    const steps = [
        obj.test.bind(obj),
        obj.fun1.bind(obj, ""),
        obj.fun2.bind(obj),
        obj.fun3.bind(obj, ""),
        obj.fun4.bind(obj, ""),
        obj.fun6.bind(obj,"",""),
    ];

    for (let fn of steps) {
        await fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for the answer... I have tried this and works like gem, but just wanna explore async.js options similar above said answer to understand its functionality.

Comment: @A.K - Just realize that many things in the async library are no longer needed now that you can code simple solutions with promises and `async/await`.  So, if you're going to use it for something, just make sure it's actually making your code cleaner and simpler vs. how it could be written without it.

Comment: yes thanks ! I’m going ahead with async/await itself as it makes code cleaner and easier too !